# PHP + MySQL: Display all records with same values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need some help regarding displaying multiple MySQL records where the date values are the same.

Example:

```
========================== 
31 July
Record 1 

2 August
Record 2
Record 3 

5 August
Record 4
Record 5 

6 August
Record 6
==========================
```

MySQL records example data:

```
nid | neventName | nstartDate
----+------------+-----------
| 1 | Record 1   | 2018-07-31 
| 2 | Record 2   | 2018-08-02 
| 3 | Record 3   | 2018-08-02 
| 4 | Record 4   | 2018-08-05 
| 5 | Record 5   | 2018-08-05 
| 6 | Record 6   | 2018-08-08
```

My code for this section is the following:

```
<?php
//DATE VALUES
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$startDate = $rs_EventsVenuesListing_rows['nstartDate'];
$date = date_create($startDate);

//CREATE SQL STATEMENT
$sql_EventsVenuesListing = "SELECT * FROM tblvenueListingsEvents WHERE $currentDate <= nstartDate ORDER BY nstartDate ASC";
//$sql_EventsVenuesListing = "SELECT DISTINCT nstartDate FROM tblvenueListingsEvents WHERE $currentDate <= nstartDate ORDER BY nstartDate ASC";

//CONNECT TO MYSQL SERVER
require('inc-conn.php');

//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT
$rs_EventsVenuesListing = mysqli_query($vconn, $sql_EventsVenuesListing);

//CREATE AN ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
//$rs_EventsVenuesListing_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_EventsVenuesListing);
?>

<?php

  echo "<table border = 1px>";
  while ($rs_EventsVenuesListing_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_EventsVenuesListing)) {
  // printing table row
  // ##### DISPLAY ALL DATES USING START DATE FROM EVENTS #####
  echo'<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$rs_EventsVenuesListing_rows['nstartDate'].'</td>';
  echo'</tr>'; // closing table row

  // ##### DISPLAY ALL EVENTS THAT HAS THE SAME START DATE #####
  if ($startDate = $startDate) {
  echo'<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$rs_EventsVenuesListing_rows['neventName'].'</td>';
  echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
  }

  echo'<tr>';
  echo '<td><br></td>';
  echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
  }

echo '</table>';
?>
<!-- ######################## DISPLAY DATES ######################## -->
```

Your assistance will gladly be appreciated.
Regards,
Dane

Comment: what is the problem/question then? What's happening now that isn't expected?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: `if ($startDate = $startDate)` - hm. two things there: `=` != `==` and second: you compare a var with itself?

Comment: and in the 3rd row you try to access `$rs_EventsVenuesListing_rows['nstartDate'];`, which isn't defined there yet.

Comment: *"what is the problem/question then? What's happening now that isn't expected?"* - About that @Jeff I agree and thought the same thing, which is why I had to vote this one as unclear. Lovely communication huh? heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplyfied snippet of how such a structure

```
Header1
  data1
  data2
Header2
  data3
...
```

works:

```
$startdate = null; // initialize

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_EventsVenuesListing)) {

    if($startdate != $row['nstartDate']) {
        // echo HEADER ROW (the date) HERE!

        // set startdate to the new one:
        $startdate = $row['nstartDate'];
    }

    // allways echo DATA ROW (Record 1) HERE

}
```

This code is not meant for copy & paste. It shall only show the logic behind.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for your time to help me out. It works perfect!
I gladly appreciate your assistance. I hope you have a great evening on wards :)